# How to know which file or inode triggered a systemd.path unit?

Tags: linux, systemd, inotify

Systemd offers unit files whom control monitoring of a certain path trough inotify: `systemd.path(5)`. If a file or directory is modified in the watched path the corresponding `systemd.service(5)` is called.

According to the `inotify(7)` man page:

> To determine what events have occurred, an application read(2)s from the inotify file descriptor.  If no events have so far occurred, then, assuming a blocking file  descriptor, read(2) will block until at least one event occurs (unless interrupted by a signal, in which case the call fails with the error EINTR; see signal(7)).
>
> Each successful read(2) returns a buffer containing one or more of the following structures:
>
> ```
>       struct inotify_event {
>           int      wd;       /* Watch descriptor */
>           uint32_t mask;     /* Mask of events */
>           uint32_t cookie;   /* Unique cookie associating related
>                                 events (for rename(2)) */
>           uint32_t len;      /* Size of name field */
>           char     name[];   /* Optional null-terminated name */
>       };
> ```

So if systemd see a change in the watched path, is there a way of getting any data from the `read(2)` command? Notably I need the `name[]` to be used as an argument to the command for the `ExecStart=` in the `systemd.service(5)` unit statement.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/command --file=$inotifyName
```

Comment: Sure there is: can you program C?

Comment: Nope. Just pointing out, that if a program is using inotify, it can include `read(2)`, to work with the event. So how does systemd use it and can I use data from `read(2)` in a systemd unit file as a variable or specifier?

Comment: It does so from within a C program: read(2) is a system all, you can check it from man man.

Comment: I know read(2) is a system call. I do not want to do anything with read(2). I want to run a command from a `systemd.service` file, triggered by a `systemd.path` file, which in turn uses inotify and I *assume* it uses something like `read(2)`. I need the a string containing the filename that triggered the event appended to the `ExecStart` statement in the unit file.

Comment: Did you find out? I'm looking at running a script as well.

Comment: @Tim I know this has been posted a while ago, nevertheless - did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, no never found (I stopped looking to be honest)

Comment: systemd doesn't pass its file descriptor that has inotify open to the called process. The python [inotify](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/) should be easy enough to script up.

Comment: It's a fair question, and I'd like to hear the same.  In particular, because I finally got the skeleton of my monitoring service moved over from inotify (!) with hope hung on using systemd Path units like inotify! :(  I feel I (we) must be overlooking something...?

Answer (score 1):

[Steward](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/272848/stewart) gave a quiet complete proposal for a reasonable workaround [on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600686/154557)

> After some playing I found the easiest way was to use one *.path file per path and template each path into a single *@.service file.

cheers

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.